# Consolidating worksheets into one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a few excel worksheets in the style of

### Organization 1

---

#### Name Occupation

Chris - contracter

Jane - employee

---

### Organization 2

---

#### Name Occupation

Bob - Facilities

Trey - Software Developer

---

And would like these worksheets to be combined into a master worksheet with the format

#### Organization Name Occupation

1 - Chris - contracter

1 - Jane - employee

2 - Bob - Facilities

2 - Trey - Software Developer

Using VBA I'm able to pull all the data into the one worksheet using

```
NumSheets = Worksheets.Count

Worksheets(1).Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "All"
For X = 1 To NumSheets
Worksheets(X + 1).Select
curAgency = ActiveSheet.Name
NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Rows("5:" & NumRows).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("All").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Paste
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Worksheets(X + 1).Select
Range("A1").Select
Next X
Worksheets("All").Select
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

But I am unsure how to insert the column and append the organization name to each group on the master list.

Comment: @charles Any reason to remove rdbmerge tag?

Comment: @Santosh, tags are for questions, not for answers.  This is not a question about the tool you suggested in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use RDBMerge add-in which will combine the data from different worksheet and create a master sheet for you. Please see the below link for more details.

http://duggisjobstechnicalstuff.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-merge-all-excel-worksheets-with.html

[Download RDBMerge](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm)

Comment: That may work for some people, but Im looking for a more vba oriented solution so I can tweak if needed.

Comment: @sko  Its freely available addin with lots of flexibility. Give it a try and you will like it.

Comment: It doesn't quite match my needs. Anyway you can supply me with the password so I can look at the VB module source?

Comment: @sko Sorry i dont have the password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem, but this could help:

```
Sub MergeAll()
Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet, rAll As Long, wsAll As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.name = "All"
Set wsAll = ActiveSheet
rAll = 2
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "All" Then
        r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To r
            wsAll.Cells(rAll, 1) = ws.name
            wsAll.Cells(rAll, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
            wsAll.Cells(rAll, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 2)
            rAll = rAll + 1
        Next i
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I guessed, that there is one Excel file with multiple sheets. Each sheet represents one organization.
So the makro will run through each sheets (except Sheet with name "All") and write the data of the sheets to "All".
I hope that is what you need.