# How to copy ALL data from 12 workbooks onto a blank one / Range Inquiry

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am almost completely new to using VBA and Macros on Excel 2010.  I know little to nothing about macro coding, and I just started a day ago trying to pick it up.

I was asked to create a macro that copies ONLY the data from 12 workbooks and pastes it onto a blank workbook (**they all have 1 sheet each, with the data on each workbook starting on cell A3 while stretching to column S (the amount of data on the sheets vary)**).

```
   NOTE: When I mean "ONLY the data," the cells that I want to be copied include the blank cells that are in between the first and last parts of the data.
```

1) When copying data from one workbook to another, do you HAVE to specify the cells that you would like to copy?  Or is there a way to specify where the data ends on the sheet, and then copy all of that data?  If so, then could someone show me how to do so?  The reason for doing so is because the macro will be used weekly.

and 2) Could someone simply help me develop this macro? Help would be massively appreciated :)

```
   Some Extra Notes:
   - The Workbooks are named "Status by offering ID [1-12]
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post an example of the data structure and clarify what you mean by there are blank cells between the first and last parts of data? Blank rows, blank columns, individual blank cells? Please be more specific.

Comment: @user2472376 Checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ripster has given one example of missing information from your specification.

Santosh recommends a pretty neat tool but my reading of your question is that your knowledge is not up to using a tool yet.

I deduce this is a work question and your boss has asked you to write this macro despite your knowledge of VBA being zero.  This seems to be a growing problem: you can discover the answer to anything on the net so why bother with training people.  Even if you produced a complete specification of your requirement, I doubt anyone will give you a complete solution.  If they do provide a complete solution, it will not help with the next requirement.  So I am going to break your problem down into the type of questions you can ask the net.

Each week you get 12 source workbooks and create a summary by consolidating data from the source workbooks. Do you overwrite the previous week's summary with the new summary or do you want to save all the summaries?  It will not add much to the complexity to keep all the summaries but you need to decide what you want.

If you discard the previous summary, the macro can be in Summary.xlxm, say.  If you save the summaries, the macro will need to be in its own workbook, Macro.xlsm say, and it will create a different summary workbook, SummaryYYWW.xlsm say, each week.

If you search for "Workbook Open" and "Workbook Create", you will find instructions on how a macro in one workbook can open other workbooks and create new workbooks.

Where are the source workbooks?  Are they in the folder CurrentData which is overwritten each week?  Are they in the folders Week1301, Week1302, Week1303 and so on?  Are they in the folder NewData and the macro is to move them to folders Week1301, Week1302, Week1303 and so on after processing?  All these are options but I suggest you start by moving the source and summary workbooks to/from a folder convenient for the macro.

Look up "ThisWorkbook" and "ActiveWorkbook".  In brief: "ThisWorkbook" is the workbook containing the macro and "ActiveWorkbook" is the most recently opened workbook.

Look up workbook property "Path".  ThisWorkbook.Path, for example, gives you the name of the folder containing ThisWorkbook.  Look up workbook property "Name".

If the source workbooks always have the same names, you could hard code the names into the macro.  I do not recommend this.  Look up the function "Dir".

I hope the above has given you a start on breaking your total problem down into its components.

There are many different VBA tutorials available on the web.  Try a few and pick one you like.

"Debug.Print xxx" outputs the value of xxx to the Immediate Window.  This can be very helpful as you start.  Try this as your first macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub First()

  Dim FilenameCrnt As String
  Dim WbookCrnt As Workbook

  Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name
  Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path

  FilenameCrnt = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.*")

  Do While FilenameCrnt <> ""
    Debug.Print FilenameCrnt
    If FilenameCrnt = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
      With ThisWorkbook
        Debug.Print "  Used range: " & .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Address
      End With
    Else
      If LCase(Right(FilenameCrnt, 3)) = "xls" Or _
         LCase(Right(FilenameCrnt, 4)) = "xlsm" Or _
         LCase(Right(FilenameCrnt, 4)) = "xlsx" Then
        WbookCrnt = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FilenameCrnt)
        With WbookCrnt
          Debug.Print "  Used range: " & .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Address
        End With
        WbookCrnt.Close
        WbookCrnt = Nothing       ' Free resource
      End If
    End If
    FilenameCrnt = Dir$
  Loop

End Sub
```

Best of luck

Comment: To be more specific, the weekly workbooks are sent to a public folder on Microsoft Outlook via email, which I open and save to my C: drive.  I send them all to one specific folder.  For the following week, would deleting the workbooks and then replacing them be more efficient?  And thanks for the help!  Greatly appreciated

Comment: Efficiency should not be an initial concern; meeting the user requirement comes first. If you need an audit trail, saving the summary workbook may important. If you are selecting data from the source workbook, you might later decide you want more data and wish to reprocess archived source files. Disk space is cheap and you can always delete files next year if not needed so I recommend saving everything.

Comment: Come back with more questions if necessary.  I have mentioned some of the statements and functions I think will be most useful to you. However, there is much more I could say if I better understood your requirement.