# How can I copy and paste a range from a closed Excel Workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

Similar to this post

[Iterate through spreadsheets in a folder and collect a value from each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722576/iterate-through-spreadsheets-in-a-folder-and-collect-a-value-from-each)

I am trying to do the same but rather than a single value, I would like to loop through up to 52 different arrays, e.g (using pseduo code) the path being external

```
For each workbook in path
 While week < 52
   week1 = path.workbook.sheet1.range(A1:J20);
   consol.range("A" & row & ":J " & row2) = week1
   row = row + 20
   row2 = row2 + 20
   week++
 Wend
Next
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you're going the copy-paste route, the workbook must be opened first.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without? I'm thinking, since the range is always fixed (A1:J20) that I can create "holder" linking to that book on a tab, and then for each workbook update cell "C1" on that holder tab which updates a placeholder range in the same book?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978391/how-can-i-read-information-from-a-specific-cell-in-a-closed-workbook-then-paste) works for you.

Comment: yes it's possible to grab all these values from closed workbooks using a loop of [ExecuteMacro4Excel](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Comment: You can use ADO, deliberate links or XLM for closed books. But for 200 cells in the range of interest, you might finding opening the files directly to be the superior approach rather than sticking to working with closed books

Comment: I wouldn't copy and paste it, or open it. I would link it with a formula, manually or with vba, where ever you want to paste it, then if you didn't want the formula, copy and paste values after.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my notes, and i got this:

```
week1="'" & path & "[" & FileName & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & _
Range("A1:J20").Range("A1").Address ( ,,xlR1C1)
```

I think it still needs some tweaking, because i was lost at the "A1" part of the code...

Does this help you ?