# Set up Excel VBA to open 40 separate folders with 40 separate Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA: Set up VBA code to open 40 separate folders with 40 separate Excel worksheets and copy and paste specific same cells from worksheets in to one large table.

Comment: Can I suggest that you have a go at this first and post your code with any specific questions that you have.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will work in excel 2003:

```
Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim wbResults As Workbook
    Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook

    Dim cntr As Integer
    cntr = 1

    With Application.FileSearch
        .NewSearch
         'Change path to suit
        .LookIn = "C:\MyDocuments\TestResults"
        .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks
         '.Filename = "Book*.xls"

        If .Execute > 0 Then 'Workbooks in folder
            For lCount = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count 'Loop through all.
                 'Open Workbook x and Set a Workbook variable to it
                Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(lCount), UpdateLinks:=0)

                    'Copy R4C9 from each workbook into range
                    wbCodeBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & cntr).Value = wbResults.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 9).Value
                    cntr = cntr + 1

                wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next lCount
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

Excel 2007 and newer try the following method.  This will open a file dialog that allows you to select a folder with all the excel file inside that you want to loop through.  Note that the file extension is .xls but can be changed if you need it to be.

```
Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim wbResults As Workbook
    Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook

    Dim cntr As Integer
    cntr = 1

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFil As String
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
      diaFolder.Show
      FolderPath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

      sPath = FolderPath & "\" 'location of files
      sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xls") 'change or add formats

    Do While sFil <> ""
        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 'opens the file
            wbCodeBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & cntr).Value = wbResults.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 9).Value
            cntr = cntr + 1

        wbResults.Close True
        sFil = Dir
    Loop

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Range("B2:B12").Select   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = R4C9  I'm trying to pick out cell R429 from each of the workbooks out of each folder. How can i specific this please? Thanks a million for the help!!

Comment: I updated the code to have a current version for excel 2007 and newer.  I tested that version but not the older 2003

Comment: Hi Portland thanks a million for all this and if i change .xls to .xlsm should that work as the spreadsheets are all macro formatted?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it with .xlsm and had no problems.  Please mark as answered if your happy with it so the question can be closed.  Thanks