# Get a value from the sheet name and cell address

Tags: excel, vba

Many times I need to get a value from multiple sheets (to some crazy workbooks - it can be up to 200 sheets). The problem is all these 200 sheets have the same structure even their name and it is crazy for me go to link one by one though these 200 sheets. Is there any way to create a user-defined function, something like

```
=getValue(sheetName,cell address)
```

I tried

```
Function GetValue(sheetName As String, cellAddress As String) As Variant
   GetSheetValue = Range(sheetName & "!" & cellAddress).Value
End Function
```

which works well until I switch between Excel files.  The function starts to return #Value which my feeling is that it tries to search for SheetA,B,C,D @A1 on other open workbooks.

[image]

Comment: If you want to consolidate all sheets and make a master file then its worth to look at [RDB Merge Addin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835)

Comment: Thanks but not really a consolidation. I just need to have a particular value (1 cell and only 1 cell) from each sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
Function GetValue(sheetName As String, cellAddress As String) As Variant
   GetSheetValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellAddress)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in VBA fairly easily. A For...Next loop would go through all 200, worksheets, returning the values. For example:

```
my_index = 1
For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> worksheet_to_store_values_on Then
    worksheet_to_store_values_on.Cells(my_index, 1).Value = _
    ws.Range(myrange).Value
    my_index = my_index + 1
  End If
Next
```

... this will loop through all worksheets in your active workbook, find the value in *myrange* on each sheet, and stores this value in the worksheet "worksheet_to_store_values_on" in row "my_index" of column A. You can adapt to your particular situation.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Your code is really helpful, I will use it in different application.