# Optimise VBA Excel Printing - Create PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I am printing a folder full of xlsx files at the moment.
I wish to optimise and make the process faster - it takes about 40seconds to send 20 pages to the printer, thats one page from 20 different files.

Can I send each of these pages to a PDF file first, then send that PDF file once to the printer (and then I can print on both sides of the page - which would be awesome)

I would prefer to do this as when the application is finished, it will be printing up to 300 pages in one hit. So i think you can see the advantages in being able to use both sides and only need to send one pdf file to the printer.

Any help will be awesome,

Current Code:

```
Sub Print_Long_Sections(ByVal LongFolderPath As String)

' ####################################################################################
' #  INTRO

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose
'     This procedure assist the user to print all the long section files in the
'     folder that they saved the files to. This saves the need to open all the files
'
'
'




' ####################################################################################
' #  DECLAIRATIONS


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' OBJECTS

Dim LongFolder       As Folder
Dim LongFile         As File
Dim OpenLong         As Workbook
Dim FileSystemObj    As New FileSystemObject


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' VARIABLES

Dim iLoopVar         As Long
Dim DefaultPrinter   As String



' ####################################################################################
' # PROCEDURE CODE


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' optimise speed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Select the Printer

DefaultPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter

MsgBox "Select your printer"

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show





'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Print the Files in the Folder:

Set LongFolder = FileSystemObj.GetFolder(LongFolderPath)              '// set the folder object to the user specified folder

For Each LongFile In LongFolder.Files                                 '// loop through all the files in the folder

    If FileSystemObj.GetExtensionName(LongFile.Path) = "xlsx" Then    '// check file is an xlsx file,

        If InStr(1, LongFile.Name, "PipeLongSec") > 0 Then            '// check file is a long section

            Set OpenLong = Workbooks.Open(LongFile.Path)              '// open the file

            OpenLong.Sheets(1).PrintOut                               '// send file to default printer

            OpenLong.Close                                            '// close the file

        End If

    End If

Next


 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Re-Set Printer to Previous Settings

 Application.ActivePrinter = DefaultPrinter



'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' END PROCEDURE

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set OpenLong = Nothing
Set LongFolder = Nothing
Set LongFile = Nothing
Set FileSystemObj = Nothing



End Sub
```

Regards,

Joe

Comment: You can avoid using `FileSystemObj` and use the `Dir` function. If you want to consolidate the worksheet and create a master file (later print) then check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835).

Comment: Not so much that excel can't manage duplex - it uses less paper in our office - better to print 150 duplex pages and bind them in a book to give to our tradesmen rather than 300 pages printed single sided.

Comment: @Santosh - I like the link - though because our organisation works with networks and each user's version of excel would need that add-in, going to be very difficult to get that to happen right now.

Comment: Great suggestions. what i think i will do is this: 1) get all the sheets into one workbook(temporary) then export to PDF - the I can just get my users to do what they want with that PDF file. the Managers will like being able to pass pipe data by email and then choose later if they want to print it.

Comment: @Santosh is there a way I can set the folder object without 'FileSystemObj'?

Comment: Yes, you may ignore the `FSO` and use `Dir` e.g. (Remove the reference to fso and comment the variable) `LongFile = Dir(LongFolderPath, vbNormal)   
     Do While LongFile <> ""
         Debug.Print LongFile
         LongFile = Dir()
     Loop`

Comment: okay i follow that - excuse my ignorance as I am new - whats the advantage in avoiding the 'FSO'? it seems to me using 'Dir' lets us stick with using strings - so I guess this means using less memory, possible a little faster too. Is that right?

Comment: 'Dir(LongFolderPath, vbNormal)' is returning a null string straight up, I checked the help documents and I don't think that should happen because there are heaps of files in LongFolderPath, what can I do here?

Comment: @Santosh all good - i changed 'LongFile = Dir(LongFolderPath, vbNormal)' to this - 'LongFile = Dir(LongFolderPath & "\*xlsx", vbNormal)' and now it returns the .xlsx files.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in creating what I needed - A way to put all my created workbooks into somthing that was easy to distribute and print.

Code does not print - creates PDF instead:

```
Sub PDF_Long_Sections(ByVal LongFolderPath As String)

' ####################################################################################
' #  INTRO

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose
'     This procedure assists the user to put all long sections from a folder into one
'     PDF file. This makes it convieniet to share the long sections & print them.
'
'
'




' ####################################################################################
' #  DECLAIRATIONS


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' OBJECTS

Dim LongFolder       As Folder
Dim LongFile         As File
Dim OpenLong         As Workbook
Dim ExportWB         As Workbook
Dim FileSystemObj    As New FileSystemObject


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' VARIABLES

Dim iLoopVar         As Long
Dim DefaultPrinter   As String
Dim DefaultSheets    As Variant
Dim FirstSpace       As Long
Dim LastSpace        As Long



' ####################################################################################
' # PROCEDURE CODE


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' optimise speed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Print the Files in the Folder:

Set LongFolder = FileSystemObj.GetFolder(LongFolderPath)              '// set the folder object to the user specified folder

DefaultSheets = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook                       '// save default setting
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1                                   '// create a one worksheet workbook
Set ExportWB = Workbooks.Add
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = DefaultSheets                       '// re-set application to default

For Each LongFile In LongFolder.Files                                 '// loop through all the files in the folder

    If FileSystemObj.GetExtensionName(LongFile.Path) = "xlsx" Then    '// check file is an xlsx file,

        If InStr(1, LongFile.Name, "PipeLongSec") > 0 Then            '// check file is a long section

            FirstSpace = InStr(1, LongFile.Name, " ")                 '// record position of first space character
            LastSpace = InStr(FirstSpace + 1, LongFile.Name, " ")     '// record position of last space character

            Set OpenLong = Workbooks.Open(LongFile.Path)              '// open the file

            OpenLong.Sheets("Long Sections").Copy After:=ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.Count)
                                                                      '// copy sheet into export workbook

            ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.Count).Name = Mid(LongFile.Name, FirstSpace + 1, LastSpace - FirstSpace - 1)
                                                                      '// rename sheet we just moved to its pipe number

            OpenLong.Close                                            '// close the file

        End If

    End If

Next


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Delete the other worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ExportWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Send Workbook to PDF - in save location

ExportWB.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, LongFolder.Path & "\" & LongFolder.Name & " " & Replace(Date, "/", "-")
ExportWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Re-Set Printer to Previous Settings

Application.ActivePrinter = DefaultPrinter



'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' END PROCEDURE

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set OpenLong = Nothing
Set LongFolder = Nothing
Set LongFile = Nothing
Set FileSystemObj = Nothing



End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Santosh's suggesting I have the Dir method also working -
unfortuantly both methods take 23-24 seconds when I apply the timer...

```
Sub DirPDF_Long_Sections(LongFolderPath As String)


' ####################################################################################
' #  INTRO

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose
'     This procedure assists the user to put all long sections from a folder into one
'     PDF file. This makes it convieniet to share the long sections & print them.
'
'     THIS PROCEDURE USES DIR instead of FSO
'




' ####################################################################################
' #  DECLAIRATIONS


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' OBJECTS

Dim LongFolder       As String
Dim LongFile         As String
Dim OpenLong         As Workbook
Dim ExportWB         As Workbook
'Dim FileSystemObj    As New FileSystemObject


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' VARIABLES

Dim count            As Long
Dim DefaultPrinter   As String
Dim DefaultSheets    As Variant
Dim FirstSpace       As Long
Dim LastSpace        As Long
Dim start_time, end_time


' ####################################################################################
' # PROCEDURE CODE


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' optimise speed

start_time = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False




'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Print the Files in the Folder:



DefaultSheets = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook                       '// save default setting
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1                                   '// create a one worksheet workbook
Set ExportWB = Workbooks.Add
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = DefaultSheets                       '// re-set application to default

LongFile = Dir(LongFolderPath & "\*PipeLongSec*", vbNormal)

While LongFile <> vbNullString                                        '// loop through all the files in the folder


                       '// check file is a long section


            FirstSpace = InStr(1, LongFile, " ")                      '// record position of first space character
            LastSpace = InStr(FirstSpace + 1, LongFile, " ")          '// record position of last space character

            Set OpenLong = Workbooks.Open(LongFile)                   '// open the file

            OpenLong.Sheets("Long Sections").Copy After:=ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.count)
                                                                      '// copy sheet into export workbook




            ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.count).Name = Mid(LongFile, FirstSpace + 1, LastSpace - FirstSpace - 1)
                                                                      '// rename sheet we just moved to its pipe number

            OpenLong.Close                                            '// close the file

            LongFile = Dir()




Wend


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Delete the other worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ExportWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Send Workbook to PDF - in save location

ExportWB.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, LongFolderPath & "\" & "LongSectionCollection " & Replace(Date, "/", "-")
ExportWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Re-Set Printer to Previous Settings




'#####################################################################################
'#  END PROCEDURE

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set OpenLong = Nothing



end_time = Now()
MsgBox (DateDiff("s", start_time, end_time))



End Sub
```