# Copy specific cells and worksheet to a specific worksheet and cells

Tags: vba, directory, copy, paste

i tried searching online to no avail. i use the specific key words to search for the right key terms to find how to solve my macro issue. I have a bit of programming backgrd but i'm not good at starting from scratch, been searching for a template to begin with but to no avail as well.

**My question is**

I have 2 sets of directory with simiarly named workbooks example A,B,C and A1,B1,C1 both in different directory but they have similarly named sheets and I would like to do a template whereby I can specify which cells and which sheets to copy and paste into.

I can't find searching within past questions past because there ain't any specific cells copy and paste into. If there is, maybe I didn't do enough digging. Could someone help me with this? Thansks!

Comment: Check out [RDBMerge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835)

Comment: I'm trying to copy one set of data from one worksheet to another at different directory? How does the consolidation of worksheets help?

Comment: Go to link above > Download the addin > follow the instructions of blog >  It will help to consolidate worksheets /workbooks. Give it a try.