# Consolidate tables on multiple worksheets to one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help on this issue.  I am using VBA in Excel 2007 to consolidate tables from five separate worksheets onto one worksheet.  This works great in a stand alone workbook, but I need to move this into a workbook with other tabs that I will not consolidate data from.  I tried creating an array as a varaible which included the five workbooks I need to consolidate, but I could not get it to work.
Here is the code I am using as a separate process that works:

```
Sub SummariseData()
    Dim x As Long, llastrow As Long, lfirstrow As Long
    Range("Data").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(x).CodeName <> "Sheet1" Then
            If Sheets(x).Range("A2") <> "" Then
                lfirstrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                llastrow = Sheets(x).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                Sheets(x).Range("A2:N" & llastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B" &          Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Sheet1.Range("A" & lfirstrow & ":A" & lfirstrow + llastrow - 2) = Sheets(x).Name
            End If
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Can anoyone help with how to write the code to specifically call the the five tabs I need to consolidate, instead of loop through all tabs in the workbook?  The tab names are T1, T2, T3, T4, T5 all consolidaing to a tab call Summary.

Comment: [**Consolidating worksheets into one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030067/consolidating-worksheets-into-one/17030835#17030835)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Summary")

For Each sh in Thisworkbook.Sheets(Array("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"))
    If sh.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        sh.Range("A1",sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0,14).Address).Copy _
        ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
        ws.Range(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Address, _
            Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0,-1).Address).Value = sh.Name
    End If
Next
```

Not tested though so i leave it to you.

Comment: Great! Didn't know you could use arrays in such a way! (I assume it is working; haven't tested either)

Comment: yep. i already tested it and it works. :) it is useful when you are updating certain sheets only.

Comment: Both solutions worked but this was simplest to me.  thank you both though for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with this :

```
Sub SummariseData()
    Dim x As Long, llastrow As Long, lfirstrow As Long

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Summary")


    Range("Data").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 1 To 5
        sheetName = "T" & x
        Set ws2 = Worksheets(sheetName)

        If ws2.Range("A2") <> "" Then
            lfirstrow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            llastrow = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            ws2.Range("A2:N" & llastrow).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ws1.Range("A" & lfirstrow & ":A" & lfirstrow + llastrow - 2) = sheetName
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

**Details on what I changed :**

1. I used worksheet objects instead of calling the worksheet by its name each time (`ws1` for the worksheet **TO** which you're copying, and `ws2` for the worksheet **FROM** which you're copying.
2. I used a loop that goes from 1 to 5, to concatenate that value to a T, in order to get the tab name.